# Get a Lua table from "compressed" string

Tags: datatable, lua

I have a problem trying to decode a Lua table which was compressed (I think) and encoded to Base64. 
I know one string comes from this table:

```
{[0] = 1, [1] = 2, [2] = 3, [3] = 4, [4] = 5}
```

It is coming from this string: `8AlMVUEAAAABBQAAAAWAAAAAAgAAAACAMQQVABEyBgDQMwQAAAABNAQAAAABNQ`, which decoded from Base64 gives this: `LUA12345`. EDIT: In the view it seems like chaining together numbers, but it's bytes look something like this:

```
00000000: c3b0 094c 5541 0000  ...LUA..
00000008: 0001 0500 0000 05c2  ........
00000010: 8000 0000 0200 0000  ........
00000018: 00c2 8031 0415 0011  ...1....
00000020: 3206 00c3 9033 0400  2....3..
00000028: 0000 0134 0400 0000  ...4....
00000030: 0135 0a              .5.
```

I was literally searching the entire Internet for this and found absolutely **nothing**.

So, my main question is: **how to decode this into a Lua table back?**

Comment: you say "I have this Lua table" and then you ask how to get that Lua table? sorry but I cannot follow you

Comment: I mean I know that table comes from the encoded string, sorry

Comment: Not enough data to reverse-engineer the coding method.  Could you provide a dozen of another different pairs "base64 + its Lua table"?

Comment: All I can say that it's ran on LuaVM (c++) with a Lua API. The api also has a function to "improve" the data which I have no idea how it works. It's also all saved in a file.